# Why vsftpd could not list directory's content?

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I serve anonymous access to `/srv/ftp`

Have drwxr-xr-x permissions on `/srv/ftp/pub` directory, owner *root*, group owner - *ftp*

Having these permissions I can login as anonymouse user to ftp server and view *pub*'s content by `ls pub`

Then I change `/srv/ftp/pub`'s permissions to drwxr-x--x and now `ls pub` does not work:

```
226 Transfer done(but failed to open directory).
```

Why one needs to allow to make directory world-readable in order to list its contents?

As I understand vsftp runs under *ftp* group so daemon should be able to display contents of pub directory but it could not.

This is my *vsftpd.conf*

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
utf8_filesystem=YES
no_anon_password=YES
hide_ids=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
max_per_ip=3
max_clients=10
```

Do you have any clues?

Comment: please could you show the results for `sudo cat /etc/vsftpd.conf`

Comment: It is long, I put sensible values there. Could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: yes i know its long but not that long, paste it so I can check your values :)

Comment: @George, I did.

Comment: Your values look Ok. So I looked at `linux permissions`, if you do `drwxr-x--x` like you did then `all other users` will never be able to read the contents of the `folder' so it must be `drwxr-xr-x` for `anonymous users` to be able to list the contents of the directory. So short answer based on what I know is you have to leave it in the form `drwxr-x-r-x`.

Comment: As I understand vsftpd runs under group "ftp"(drops permission to that special group) so it could already server that firectory, it is not "other".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49315/discussion-between-george-and-bulat-m).